# Load related data when adding an entity - Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When adding an entity the Add function returns `EntityEntry`, however the returned entity does not contain any related data.

I can use:

```
public async Task<Category> Add(Category model)
{
    var entityEntry = await _applicationContext.Categories.AddAsync(model);
    await entityEntry.Reference(x => x.Parent).LoadAsync();
    await _applicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entityEntry.Entity;
}
```

But to my understanding this lazy loads the data.

Is there a better way?

Comment: yes, just search for `Include` and `ThenInclude` in Entity Framework Code

Comment: Yeah, that only works for selecting data, not adding. I can create a new request and select it at the end, but that is even worse than what I put in my example.

Comment: Didn't ger your question

Comment: When using the Add function, there is no way you can chain `Include` and `ThenInclude`.  You can do it explicitly, example in the code I submitted in the question, but that lazy loads the navigation property.

If there is a way to add `Include` to the chain and then use the Add function, therefore eagerly loading the related data please let me know.